# why my Makefile does not make *.mod when I use Makefile

Tags: makefile, module, fortran

I am trying to make simple Makefile to build my program.

My `Makefile` file is as below:

`main.f` is main source code and `test1.f` is module.

```
default: test.out

test.out : main.o test1.o
    gfortran main.o test1.o -o test.out

test1.o: test1.f
    gfortran -c test1.f

main.o: main.f
    gfortran -c main.f


clean :
    rm -f ./*.out
    rm -f ./*.o
    rm -f ./*.mod
```

when I command `make` in the terminal it gives me the error that

```
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file 'test1.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

(1) shows the where the error happens. It is in the line of main source file where I define to use module test1
i.e. `use test1`

If I command `gfortran -c test1.f` then command `make` it builds the executable file without any issues.

My question is that even I wrote the line for making objective file in the Makefile for the module, why it does not work?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your Makefile dependencies are wrong.  You need to compile test1.f90 before main.f90.  So change `test.out : main.o test1.o` to `test.out: test1.o main.o`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that the sequence of dependencies matters even in the dependencies section. Thanks man!

Comment: This is not the best way to do it.  Just putting things in a different order in the dependency list doesn't guarantee that the second one will wait for the first one to complete.  If you run `make -j` your makefile will still fail.  If it's the case that the `main.o` target depends on the output of the `test1.o` target, you must tell make that this is the case by adding a prerequisite line: `main.o : test1.o`.  Now it doesn't matter what order they are listed in the prerequisites, make knows that they depend on each other.

Comment: Why would one use -j when a Makefile has only two files?  Also not sure why there is a down vote.  The first sentence in my answer is indisputable.  Technically, @MadScientist's comment is also incorrect.  main.f depends on the existence of `test1.mod`.  One would need to have `main.o: test1.mod` and `test1.mod: test1.f` and in the new world order of submodules one may need additional dependency involving `*.smod` files.

Comment: Downvote wasn't me.  However, it's not the case that a source file can depend on a generated file.  You can't rebuild a source file, there's no recipe for it, so it cannot have a prerequisite.  Just like a `.c` file doesn't depend on a `.h` file; the `.o` depends on the `.h`, even though the `.c` includes the `.h`.  And, just because this example has only two files doesn't mean the real version won't have more.  Either way, there's value in writing the makefile correctly (and understanding why it's correct) even if the result is the same.